# Clarification regarding Bin.asNull vs real null value vs thombstone

Tags: aerospike

I'm looking for some clarification regarding what happening and how it affects the inter and between cluster replication between the following operations:

```scala
 def test() = {
    val key = new Key("ns", Configuration.dummySetName, 2)
    client.put(null, key, new Bin("bin0", Value.NULL)) // Is that Thombstone? All Row Will be deleted?
    client.put(null, key, new Bin("bin2", "value1")) // set bin2 value to be value1
    client.put(null, key, Bin.asNull("bin2")) // Is that deleted on the commit? any zombie records can be with value1? is it shipped via XDR? is durableDelete change something?
    val record = client.get(null, key)
    println(record)
  }
```

1. What put tombstone means? Is it’s shipped via XDR? can it create “zombie records״?
2. What are the difference between durable delete and non durable delete? Is they shipped between clusters via XDR? i got the durable delete true means that it’s create tombstone, which back me to 1
3. What’s the difference between put null in specific bin to use bin.asNull and put tombstone? Is they all shipped?

I’m a bit confused,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A durable delete will create a tombstone, which is a small record that will stay in the system until all previous versions of the record it covers are gone (and some other side conditions). Details on the [Durable Delete](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/guide/durable_deletes.html) doc.

Tombstones prevent 'zombie' records or records resurrection after a cold restart.

Both durable and non durable deletes are shipped by XDR. There is a different mechanism for non durable deletes, though. Durable deletes (or tombstones) are shipped as any other records.

Putting null in a specific bin will delete that bin. If it is the last remaining bin in the record, it will delete the record, and the delete will be durable if the durable delete policy is set on the write that nullifies the bin. I don't know the difference between writing null in a bin and using the Bin.asNull. I would expect it to be the same if I had to guess.

Comment: Amazing @Meher, thanks! - Regarding the last section, its indeed seems like its the same, but what about put as real `null` in a specific bin, is that possible put such as value? what its doing, is that different from Tombstone? (I'm asking because i heard that Aerospike will just delete the whole record which its like Tombstone no?)

Comment: A tombstone of a record has same key with all bins null. Its only created when you write with writepolicy durable_delete true. Any bin of a record that you set to null_value is deleted from the record. When you set the last bin in a record to null, the record is deleted. If the writepolicy is durable_delete true when you set the last bin to null, the record's tombstone (same key, all bins null) stays in system. Otherwise the record is simply deleted. The tombstone is automatically removed by Aerospike when it is not needed anymore. Its tells Aerospike that this record was durably deleted.

Comment: You meant that in `durable delete = true` so the record is simply deleted? and in false its can re-created during cold start? so is there some benefits from using `durable delete = false`?

Comment: Yes, if durable delete is true and a record gets deleted (either directly or by setting its last remaining bin value to nil), it will create a tombstone and will prevent the record from being resurrected on a cold restart. But you have to plan for more space in your index as records will linger longer in the index when durably deleted (details on the doc previously shared).

Comment: Hey Again :) - What about `client.truncate`, is truncate command shipped via XDR?

Comment: Good question, truncate is not shipped via XDR.

Comment: Just to understand `Both durable and non durable deletes are shipped by XDR. There is a different mechanism for non durable deletes, though. Durable deletes (or tombstones) are shipped as any other records.` - How non durable delete happens? how its shipped via XDR and what is the difference between them if so?

Comment: I mean if we non-durubable delete record, how its dropped from disk and how its dropped from other regions via XDR?

Comment: It is briefly described in the link initially shared: "Starting with XDR 5.0, due to the absence of digest log, XDR creates xdr_tombstones to ship non-durable deletes. These xdr tombstones are reclaimed when the LST (Last Ship Time) of XDR is greater than the LUT (Last Update Time) of the xdr tombstones, or in other word, when they have been successfully shipped."